# ColdFusion List Error Invalid list index 2

Tags: coldfusion

I am getting an Invalid Index 2 error. Though the loop is quite simple

```
<cfset empID = 3333333>
<cfset Sec_skill = 2,5>
<cfset SecSkillLevel=1,2>

<cfloop from="1" to="#listLen(Sec_skill)#" index="i"> 
 <cfoutput>
    #ListgetAt(empID,i)# <br>
    #ListGetAt(sec_skill,i)#<br>
    #ListGetat(SecSkillLevel,i)#<br>
</cfoutput>
</cfloop>

Need help
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error will be on this line:

`#ListgetAt(empID,i)#`

empID is not a list, so there is no element 2.

Answer (score 0):

empID has no item in the list at index 2, there is only one item.
Before displaying, it is necessary to check if the item exist in the list.

**For example, with convert list to array:**

```
<cfset empID = 3333333>
<cfset Sec_skill = "2,5">
<cfset SecSkillLevel= "1,2">


<cfloop array="#listToArray(Sec_skill)#" item="item" index="i">
     <cfoutput>
        #ArrayIsDefined(listToArray(empID), i) ? listToArray(empID)[i] : '-'# <br>
        #ArrayIsDefined(listToArray(sec_skill), i) ? listToArray(sec_skill)[i] : '-'# <br>
        #ArrayIsDefined(listToArray(SecSkillLevel), i) ? listToArray(SecSkillLevel)[i] : '-'# <br>
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```